# Cordova/PhoneGap HTML5 GeoFence

Tags: android, html, cordova, geofencing

I am looking to add some Geofencing to my Cordova/PhoneGap 3.0 app for Android.

Does anyone have any experience using any of the plugins out there? Or if you could suggest the best method of going about calculating geofences inside of my app in an efficient manner?

Right now I have it so that it auto updates every 5 seconds and checks it against predefined points in the local code, if the user is in the radius or not. Just it seems a bit taxing on the system. Any suggestions would be awesome!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also

https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence

You will even find there some [example application](https://github.com/cowbell/ionic-geofence) built with ionic framework.

Comment: Does this have the capability to run in the background?